# Jquery multiple file usage

Tags: jquery

I am unable to use multiple jquery file in a single page.
Tried using noconflict but it has not helped out. One jquery is for sliding panel and another for collapsible window.

I am using the following jquery files.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the latest version. There shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: It's no acceptable to include many versions in single page.

Answer (score 0):

There are two choices:

1. Use the latest version it will work for you.
2. Ordering of the file, the reference to older on must be first then new version.

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest. For now it is:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js